# adding months to date, fraction

Tags: google-sheets

Looking around i see the Edate formula to add months, but im working with fractions. eg 2.8. I'm looking to add not only the 2 months, but also the days roughly; more to get a idea how close day wise it is to the next month.

Break down; the fraction is gained from dividing the reserve fund by the monthly loss. Im then looking to take the start of the current month and adding the fraction in months/days to get an idea how much further the reserve will last.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: ok, and? Your formulas? What have you tried already? What results did they give?

Comment: Ive googled around a bit, all Ive found is the Edate formula, its close as it rounds the fraction and just adds that, but i've not found any other way.

Comment: There are 365.2422 days in a year, so you can take the fractional part of `2.8` (or whatever the input is) and calculate (365.2422 / 12) * fractional_part to find how many days are in that fractional part. then you can add that amount to the output of Edate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `2.8` in A1 please try:

```
=edate(eomonth(today(),-1),A1)+mod(A1,1)*365.24/12
```

`eomonth(today(),-1)` saves entering the start of the current month. As you know the `edate` part will move forward from the start of the current month by the number of months of the integer part [`2`] of A1. `mod(A1,1)` then takes the decimal part of A1 [`0.8`] for multiplication by `365.24/12` (the approximate number of days, on average, in a month) to move further forward by adding that number of days to the result of `edate`.